# index 60 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 60

Tags: python-3.x, indexing, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a problem with my code and no matter what I do, I always get the index out of bounds error

I tried changing 60 to 40 or 80 but I always have the same problem

```
def Talus(Nbriter,taille):
M=np.zeros([taille,taille],int)
avalanch=[]
duree=[]
perte=[]
for gain in range(Nbriter):
    iaj=rd.randint(1,taille-1)
    jaj=rd.randint(1,taille-1)
    M[iaj][jaj]+=1
    a=1
    atot=0
    d=0
    perdu=0
    while a>0:
        for i in range(1,taille-1):
            for j in range(1,taille-1):
                if (M[i][j]-M[i][j+1]>3) or (M[i][j]-M[i][j-1]>3) or (M[i] 
                    [j]-M[i+1][j]>3) or (M[i][j]-M[i-1][j]>3):
                    M[i][j]-=4
                    M[i][j+1]+=1
                    M[i][j-1]+=1
                    M[i+1][j]+=1
                    M[i-1][j]+=1
                    a+=4
                    d+=1
                else:
                    a=0
                atot+=a
                for i in range(taille):
                    perdu+=M[i][0]
                    M[i][0]=0
                    perdu+=M[i][-1]
                    M[i][-1]=0
                for j in range(taille):
                    perdu+=M[0][j]
                    M[0][j]=0
                    perdu+=M[-1][j]
                    M[-1][j]=0

            avalanch.append(atot)
            duree.append(d)
            perte.append(perdu)
        return(M,avalanch,duree,perte)


     M,avalanch,duree,perte=Talus(100000,40)
```

I always get this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Poste1\Desktop\mon tipe\codeavalanche2.py", line 52, in 
  <module>
   M,avalanch,duree,perte=Talus(100000,40)
   File "C:\Users\Poste1\Desktop\mon tipe\codeavalanche2.py", line 26, 
   in Talus
       if (M[i][j]-M[i][j+1]>3) or (M[i][j]-M[i][j-1]>3) or (M[i][j]- 
    M[i+1][j]>3) or (M[i][j]-M[i-1][j]>3):
     IndexError: index 40 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 40
```

It's for a project I need to submit, so please if anyone knows how I can fix it I would be very grateful. Thank you

By the way, my professor told me to change the range into xrange but I am using python 3 so it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you have some sort of problem understanding the way array indexes work in programming, as Python uses the classic `0 to (size-1)` type of notation. Let me explain myself:

I think your problem is the index you are trying to access is relative to the size of the array. That is, you are using `taille` for the size and `j`, that in the last iteration is going to be `j = taille-1`. Here comes the problem, as your array is always going to be of a given size, determined by `taille`, let's say `taille = 5`, and then in the last iteration of `j`, `(j+1) = (taille-1)+1 = taille = 5` => `M[5] -> ERROR`.

The error is completely reasonable, as array's indexes work in this way:

```
Element 1, Element 2, Element 3, Element 4, Element 5.
Index   0, Index   1, Index   2, Index   3, Index   4.
```

Or as I said in the beginning, the indexes go `from 0 to (size-1)`, and that means you cannot access the `taille-th` element of an array size `taille`.

As to the solution to your problem, if you really want to access `i+1` and `j+1`, you should then change the limits of your `for` loop from `(1, taille-1)` to `(1, taille-2)` in both cases.

Hope you found my answer helpful : )

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I do understand and i tried that but it still didn't work

Comment: Are you still getting the same error? I don't know if I'd be able to help you 100%, but some more detail would be really helpful : )

Comment: hello , yes I am still getting the same error even though i understood you completely but i think i might have something wrong on my code , I just want it to work, all i need is the 3D image